# How to change user privileges from 'Y' to 'N' in MySQL Server?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, security, root

I want to change a privilege to my glpiuser from 'N' to 'Y'.
In MySQL server, what is the command to do this task?
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgW0q.png)'s the image that display my users.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Please don't post images of text; images are often hard to read (or unreadable for people with visual impairments), they can't be used by search engines, and text can't be copied from them. Edit your question and replace the link to the image with text. Regarding the question, to grant privileges, use the [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) statement.

Answer (score 0):

The GRANT statement enables system administrators to grant privileges and roles, which can be granted to user accounts and roles.

The REVOKE statement revokes one or more privileges from a user account.

So, something like this will most likely do what you need:

```
REVOKE All ON <DB> FROM user@source;
```

Comment: `REVOKE` is more clumsy than implied here.